# I want to use Between operator in mysql but not working fine

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to solve the problems. I'm having a difficulty in using `BETWEEN` operator in `VIEW`.

My query not working fine

```
CREATE VIEW IT_SERVICE_VIEW 
AS
SELECT `it_service_ticket`.ASSIGNEDTO
        ,`it_service_ticket`.status
        ,`it_service_ticket`.REQUEST_DATE
        ,`it_service_ticket`.XETR
        ,`it_service_ticket`.FEEDBACK_RATE
        ,`it_problem`.etr
        ,`city_master`.city_name
FROM `it_service_ticket`
INNER JOIN `it_problem`
ON `it_service_ticket`.`it_problem_id`=`it_problem`.`it_problem_id`
INNER JOIN `city_master`
ON `it_service_ticket`.cityid=`city_master`.city_id
WHERE `xetr` BETWEEN '1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM' AND '3/3/2017 12:00:00 PM';
```

Comment: What do you want to achive? How looks your data table? What is the problem? What is the output do you expect?

Comment: I want to create view in specific time period. in where clause I want to use date

Comment: Have you tried to convert the date sting into type date first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date formats in your `BETWEEN` clause are wrong.  They should be in a standard format, something like this:

```
BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-03 12:00:00'
```

As it stands now, your query/view would be comparing the `xetr` column against those timestamps being treated as *text*, which is not what you want.

Comment: I want to create view on particular time period. such as three month.

Comment: xetr also datatime datatype